# Read/Write to serial port (for UBW)

Tags: c#, serial-port, communication

I'm trying to program the UBW in C# to take a command and give me the input back. For example, when I establish the USB connection in TeraTerm, a input v would give me a output of the current firmware version of the UBW I'm using.

I have the connection established in C#. I think I'm sending the command right, but my datareceived handler is never called in the debugger.

Here is the code to try to write to the port:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
           //write command to port
           port.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial port is closed! Try again!");
        }

        textBox1.Clear();

    }
```

Here is the code to try to read from it (which is never called from the debugger)

```
private void port_dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            port.ReadLine();

        }

        catch { }

    }
```

Here is the UBW home page to show how it works. http://schmalzhaus.com/UBW/

My comboBox code to set up my port:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string portName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        port = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_dataReceived);
        try
        {
            port.Open();
            //port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_dataReceived);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The selected serial port cannot be opened!");
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into TeraTerm's COM port properties, and make sure you're using the same properties in your code.

Try using this class (it wraps up a lot of serial stuff to make it easier):

http://code.google.com/p/flux3gui/source/browse/Flux3GUI/SerialCommunication.cs?r=b4a4f8546b936eeabe60b7de32e3027493498dc6

Comment: From TeraTerm, i know that the baud rate is 9600, Parity = none, databits = 8, and stopbits = one. I use a combobox to select the COM, and here is the code I use to set it up. I updated my original post to include where I set up the port and open it. From what I can tell from that link, port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_dataReceived); should send my code to my port_dataReceived method once there is data in the buffer. For some reason though, it doesn't.

Comment: Okay I'm a idiot I was using a CS lab to do my program and completely forgot that the UBW firmware isn't installed on the computer. It works on my laptop.